# didReceiveLocalNotification is not firing if app deleted from background when notification comes in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have set a local notification which gets fired at definite interval and when i click on the banner than "didReceiveLocalNotification" is called.Now when i delete the app from background , Notification comes and again when i tab on the banner but this time "didReceiveLocalNotification" not called.Please tell me how to know for notification firing in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If the application is not running in the background ***didReceiveLocalNotification*** will not call instead ***application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*** is getting called. In the launch options you can check the notification

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// If application is launched due to alarm notification, provide the option to snooze it.
UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

  if (notification)
  {
    // application is launched due to notification
  }
}
```